# firebase read users/{uid} from javascrpipt

Tags: firebase

in react firebase i am trying to read user data and snapshot is giving value null

code to read user is :

```
 constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);

    /* Helper */

    this.serverValue = app.database.ServerValue;
    this.emailAuthProvider = app.auth.EmailAuthProvider;

    /* Firebase APIs */

    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();



  }

 this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser: any) => {
      if (authUser) {
        this.db.ref(`users/${authUser.uid}`)
          .once('value')
          .then(snapshot => {
            const dbUser = snapshot.val(); // RETURNING NULL ISSUE ISSUE

            // default empty roles
            if (!dbUser.roles) {
              dbUser.roles = {};
            }

            // merge auth and db user
            authUser = {
              uid: authUser.uid,
              email: authUser.email,
              emailVerified: authUser.emailVerified,
              providerData: authUser.providerData,
              ...dbUser,
            };
            this.authUser = authUser;
            next(authUser);
          }).catch((err) => {
            fallback();
          });
      } else {
        fallback();
      }
    });
```

i have checked that authUser.uid is a valid uid - ojaGkteKX7evSEakaSlA8CZNBMJ3

screenshot from the same user in my firebase :

[image]

realtime database rules:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read":true,
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

cloud firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId}{
    allow read, delete;
  }

  }



}
```

Comment: Do you have a node `users/uid` in the Reatime Database? As a matter of fact such node is not cretaed automatically when you create a user, and you don't show any screenshot or export of your Reatime Database

Comment: Add ur database to the question

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i didnt created any users node in the realtime database , i primarily using cloud firestore there , relatime datbase is empty - i was assuming when a user is created in firebase a users node automatically created in firebase.

Comment: @techagrammer As Peter has indicated in his answer you need to create these records in the DB. You can do it in Firestore or in the RTDB.

Answer (score 0):

> I was assuming when a user is created in firebase a users node automatically created in firebase

If you want the above to occur then you can use cloud function, and use the firebase authentication trigger:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
 const root = admin.database().ref();
 ref.child("users").child(user.uid).set({
  email: user.email,
  displayName: user.displayName
  });
});
```

For more info you can check the following:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started